# PHP expects T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM?

Tags: php, runtime-error, syntax-error, error-code

Does anyone have a `T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM`?

Comment: Sometimes this is PHP's way to tell you you are missing a $ sign...  for example if you write _SESSION["foo"] instead of $_SESSION["foo"]

Comment: I know this is an old question, but the short answer is that PHP is (mis-)interpreting a constant as a class name. Some operations, such as `empty`, won’t evaluate expressions which include constants. Therefore they will try to interpret a constant as a class name and expect it to have a `::` to indicate a static property. And, of course, if you forget the `$` on a variable, it is mis-interpreted as a constant. Much of this madness, if not the error message, is fixed in later versions of PHP.

Answer (score 385, accepted):

It’s the double colon operator [`::`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) (see [list of parser tokens](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/tokens.php)).

Comment: Not really. Test this `var_dump(empty(TRUE))`

Comment: No. I just added an evaluation that returns the same T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM. I found it by mistake.

Comment: It shows when $ is missing from variable. I got it today and reached this post. In a foreach($cats as cat) then use the same cat in next line shows the error.  But the answer says about :: and the person accepted it....??

Comment: @Web_Developer, the reason that happens is because if you have a `foreach($cats as cat` the only acceptable character after the `cat` for a syntactically valid statement is a `::`, as it would allow you to specify a static property of some class called `cat`. Eg, if `cat` class has a public static member called `$mouse`, then `foreach($cats as cat::$mouse)` is perfectly valid `php`, but a statement with anything other than `::` after the `cat` would be a syntax error. If `$mouse` were not a declared property of `cat` you would get a fatal error, but still not a syntax error.

Comment: For me, it was because I had (my own personal code example of the error)

`$tokenStatus = $tokenSystem->SecurityAuthenticationTokens::CheckAuthenticationToken($data['hashedPLToken']);`

I should NOT have had the :: (static) in there mixed with the -> operator since it was an instantiated class.  My fix was...

`$tokenStatus = $tokenSystem->CheckAuthenticationToken($data['hashedPLToken']);`

Comment: var_dump(empty(TRUE)) , just return bool(false) in PHP 7.2

Answer (score 149):

It's [Hebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_language) for "double colon".

Comment: PHP - the only language where you can add an error message in Hebrew only and people accept your commit.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen **P**erplexing **H**ebrew **P**arser.

Comment: I don't think they needed anyone to approve their commit (:

Answer (score 65):

It’s a name for the `::` operator in PHP. It literally means "double colon". For some reason they named it in Hebrew. Check your code syntax, and put a `::` where appropriate :-)

Comment: Functions are in English, but that error is in Hebrew. I'm not sure if any other errors are in Hebrew though.

Comment: Highlight string is להדגיש מחרוזת.

From now on, I will only use my custom array_push function לדחוף_מערך in Hebrew characters, of course. I'm sure all of my non-Hebrew speaking coworkers will love it. Just about all of our dev team speaks at least one language written in non-latin characters. Should be fun :)

Comment: @Ilya Birman      It does not literally mean "double colon"; it literally means "two times, double dots"

Comment: @Sapphire_Brick Well yes, but actually no. ;) The word in Hebrew for "colon" (the character, not the organ) IS "nekudotayim", which literally does mean "double dots". So it's 100% correct to translate the Hebrew term as either "double double dots" or "double colon".

Answer (score 57):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator):

> In PHP, the scope resolution operator is also called Paamayim
>   Nekudotayim (Hebrew: פעמיים נקודתיים‎), which means “double colon” in
>   Hebrew.
>
> The name "Paamayim Nekudotayim" was introduced in the
>   Israeli-developed Zend Engine 0.5 used in PHP 3. Although it has been
>   confusing to many developers who do not speak Hebrew, it is still
>   being used in PHP 5, as in this sample error message:
>
> $ php -r :: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
>   T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM
>
> As of PHP 5.4, error messages concerning the scope resolution operator
>   still include this name, but have clarified its meaning somewhat:
>
> $ php -r :: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '::'
>   (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM)

From [the official PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php):

> The Scope Resolution Operator (also called Paamayim Nekudotayim) or in
>   simpler terms, the double colon, is a token that allows access to
>   static, constant, and overridden properties or methods of a class.
>
> When referencing these items from outside the class definition, use
>   the name of the class.
>
> As of PHP 5.3.0, it's possible to reference the class using a
>   variable. The variable's value can not be a keyword (e.g. self, parent
>   and static).
>
> Paamayim Nekudotayim would, at first, seem like a strange choice for
>   naming a double-colon. However, while writing the Zend Engine 0.5
>   (which powers PHP 3), that's what the Zend team decided to call it. It
>   actually does mean double-colon - in Hebrew!

Comment: It's actually colloquial Hebrew. Wikipedia now says: "In PHP, the scope resolution operator is also called Paamayim Nekudotayim (Hebrew: פעמיים נקודותיים‎, pronounced [paʔaˈmajim nəkudoˈtajim], the second word a colloquial corruption of נקודתיים, pronounced [nəkudaˈtajim]), which means “double colon” in Hebrew."

Answer (score 25):

I know Hebrew pretty well, so to clarify the name "Paamayim Nekudotayim" for you, the paraphrased meaning is "double colon", but translated literally:

- "Paamayim" means "two" or "twice"
- "Nekudotayim" means "dots" (lit. "holes")

  - In the Hebrew language, a *nekuda* means a dot.
  - The plural is *nekudot*, i.e, dots, which function as vowels
  - The reason it why it's called Nekudo-*tayim* is because the suffix "-ayim" also means "two" or "twice", thus `::` denotes "two times, two dots", or more commonly known as the [Scope Resolution Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator).

Comment: What do you mean by "dots that act like vowels do in English"? The "Nekudot" here represent the two dots that a colon (:) is a compound of. Are you referring to [Niqqud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niqqud)? This concept is not related, even though both words have the same root.

Comment: Also, The "-ayim" suffix means *twice*, "Paam" means *time*. So "Paamayim" means *two times* or *twice*. "Nekuda" is *a dot*, and "Nekudot" is the plural of "Nekuda" - *many dots*. Here again, the "-ayim" suffix means "twice". So we get: *Twice many dots twice* - doesn't make much sense...

The reason is that "Nekudotaym" is actually the **wrong** spelling and pronunciation of the word. It's a mistake made by the PHP developers. It should be "Nekud**a**tayim" - meaning, *twice a "Nekuda"* or *two dots*. So it actually means: *Twice two dots*, which make much more sense.

Comment: @Sipo I was trying to avoid explaining the technical details. _Nekudot_ (נקודות) are vowels. Regarding your second point, the typo in the word is another unrelated issue with the error message.

Comment: @Sipo Why not? Do you mean the fact that _nekudot_ can be omitted, despite the risk of ambiguity?

Comment: No. I mean that vowels in Hebrew have another name: *Tnu'ot*, and they are visually repesnted by graphic symbols called *Niqqud*, not *Nekudot*. Although both words come from *Nekuda*, they are not the same. A double colon has nothing to do with vowels.

Comment: It purely sounds like Tamil language..
As mentioned..
"Paamayim" means "two" or "twice" - Panmai means plural in Tamil
"Nekudotayim" means "dots" (lit. "holes") - Ottai means hole in Tamil

'yim' we usually use to conjoint next word..

Answer (score 14):

This is also coming when you apply a constant in PHP to the empty() function:

```
if (!empty(SOME_CONSTANT)) {

}
```

That was my case. I solved it by using this:

```
$string = SOME_CONSTANT;
if (!empty($string)) {

}
```

Comment: Why would a constant be empty?

Comment: Nice Question : This is just for example if some else got in this error situation , i just show it will be also possible :)

Comment: @Don't Panic: Why not? empty() not only tests if a variable exists, but also if it's value is "empty" (in case of PHP a zero (0) is also empty). Such a constant could represent a value which is meant to be changed by a user - like DB settings or some true / false values and other value types which the code developer don't know at design-time. This is common for APIs or code frameworks. I just don't understand why the developers of the Zend parser didn't used a common word that everybody knows and understands but instead some hebrew words. I mean, it's not even really funny or so.

Comment: I use constants in config files, and I want to know in code if a specific constant is empty (null, false, 0, empty string, emty array....). Should I test against all of them manually ? WTF

Answer (score 6):

**Edit**: Unfortunately, as of PHP 8.0, the answer **is not** "No, not anymore". [This RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/rename-double-colon-token) was not accepted as I hoped, proposing to change `T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM` to `T_DOUBLE_COLON`; but it was declined.

**Note**: I keep this answer for historical purposes. Actually, because of the creation of the RFC and the votes ratio at some point, I created this answer. Also, I keep this for hoping it to be accepted in the near future.

Answer (score 4):

This can happen on foreachs when using:

```
foreach( $array as $key = $value )
```

instead of

```
foreach( $array as $key => $value )
```

Comment: This only happens in PHP 7.0, and is no longer the case as of PHP 8.0: https://3v4l.org/HScA4

Answer (score 2):

For me this happened within a class function.

In PHP 5.3 and above `$this::$defaults` worked fine; when I swapped the code into a server that for whatever reason had a lower version number it threw this error.

The solution, in my case, was to use the keyword `self` instead of `$this`:

`self::$defaults` works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

This just happened to me in a string assignment using double quotes.  I was missing a closing curly on a POST variable...

`"for {$_POST['txtName'] on $date"`;

should have been

`"for {$_POST['txtName']} on $date"`;

I can't explain why.  I mean, I see the error that would break the code but I don't see why it references a class error.

Answer (score -1):

This just happened to me in a foreach loop. I had inadvertently typed `($array as $key as $value)` and PHP objected to the first `as`.