# PHP: variable class in a class property - why calling static method return parse error?

Tags: php, oop, static-methods, parse-error, php-parse-error

Since PHP version 5.3 we can [call static method in a variable class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) like this:

```
class A 
{
    public static function foo()
    {
        echo 'bar';
    }
}

$myVariableA = A::class;

$myVariableA::foo(); //bar
```

So, given the examples below, I'd like to understand why Class B works and Class C does not:

```
class A 
{
    public static function foo()
    {
        echo 'bar';
    }
}

class B 
{
    protected $myVariableA;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->myVariableA = A::class;
    }

    public function doSomething()
    {
        $myVariableA = $this->myVariableA;
        return $myVariableA::foo(); //bar (no error)
    }
}

class C
{
    protected $myVariableA;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->myVariableA = A::class;
    }

    public function doSomething()
    {
        return $this->myVariableA::foo(); //parse error
    }
}

$b = new B;
$b->doSomething();

$c = new C;
$c->doSomething();
```

Note that **I'm not** trying to solve the issue here, but I want to understand exactly why it happens (with implementation details, if possible).

Comment: just a parser "feature", much like `echo "$foo[1][2]"` outputs `Array[2]` instead of whatever's stored at the `[2]` index.

Comment: @john-conde I don't think its duplicate. In the referred question, the guy is trying to access a method of a instanced object with '::' when he should use '->'. I'm trying to call a static method of a class that was not instanced. The code works with a local variable, but does not with a class property and I want to understand why.

Comment: @MarcB I would like to understand why the second case works (with local variable) and the first one (with the class property) does not. If we can use '::' in a local variable to call a static method, why we cannot use it in a class property?

Comment: I have edited this question for clarity. Is there any way to unmark it as duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966010/what-does-this-mean-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-paamayim-nekudotay), the error message is something to with the double semicolon ( ::).

On your doSomething(), try using myVariableA->foo();

Comment: The question is not about what T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM is. I know it means :: and it's also mapped as T_DOUBLE_COLON (I'll edit the question  to clarify, thanks).