# Unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM in PHP 5.2.x

Tags: php, php-5.2

I'm having a hard time understanding why I'm getting an `Unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM` error in the following code, which seems perfecly valid to me...

```
class xpto
{
    public static $id = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public static function getMyID()
    {
        return self::$id;
    }
}

function instance($xpto = null)
{
    static $result = null;

    if (is_null($result) === true)
    {
        $result = new xpto();
    }

    if (is_object($result) === true)
    {
        $result::$id = strval($xpto);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

**Output in PHP 5.3+:**

```
echo var_dump(instance()->getMyID()) . "\n"; // null
echo var_dump(instance('dev')->getMyID()) . "\n"; // dev
echo var_dump(instance('prod')->getMyID()) . "\n"; // prod
echo var_dump(instance()->getMyID()) . "\n"; // null
```

In [prior versions](http://codepad.org/wpT0g3VH) however, I can't do `$result::$id = strval($xpto);`, does anyone know why?

Are there any workarounds for this problem?

Comment: I copy/pasted your code to a php file, and it runs without errors.

Comment: @Chris: What PHP version are you using? Also, check this link: http://codepad.org/wpT0g3VH.

Comment: Sorry, misinterpreted your question.  Posted answer below.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP expects T\_PAAMAYIM\_NEKUDOTAYIM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592322/php-expects-t-paamayim-nekudotayim)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at codepad:

```
if (is_object($result) === true)
{
    $result::id = strval($xpto);
}
```

... should be

```
if (is_object($result) === true)
{
    $result::$id = strval($xpto);
}
```

I corrected this in a new paste, and the error still exists... just letting you know about the problem in the demo code.

**EDIT**

Per PHP documentation page on `static` keyword,

> As of PHP 5.3.0, it's possible to
>   reference the class using a variable.
>   The variable's value can not be a
>   keyword (e.g. self, parent and
>   static).

Unfortunately, no detail is given as to WHY to was otherwise in prior versions, nor do I see a workaround presented in the comments.

Because the class is static, though, you should be able to change the property directly:

```
function instance($xpto = null)
{
    static $result = null;

    if (is_null($result) === true)
    {
        $result = new xpto();
    }

    if (is_object($result) === true)
    {
        xpto::$id = strval($xpto)
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Oops, that was a typo! Still getting the error though (http://codepad.org/wpT0g3VH).

Comment: Interestingly, my dev server (php 5.2.7) calls the original error a "Parse error: parse error" rather than trotting out the old "T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM" chestnut.

Comment: Actually, you gave me a very good tip: http://codepad.org/Y9ntbREa. Thank you! =)

Answer (score 3):

The reason for the error is simply that the syntax isn't supported in `<` 5.3.

However, if you're trying to just access the static variable $id, then the syntax would be:

`$result::id`

If you do need to access a static variable variable, then a workaround is to use reflection:

```
$class = new ReflectionClass($xpto);
echo $class->setStaticPropertyValue ('id', strval($xpto));
```

[ReflectionClass](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php)

Comment: Auch, that is a PITA... `$id` in this case is not a variable variable. Do you know where I can read more about the support of this syntax? I've noticed that non-static properties also don't work (http://codepad.org/Fb1mQOvx), is this also because the syntax not being supported?

Comment: You're getting the new error because you're using $this in a static function. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: Oh yes, forgot about that! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

PHP Version 5.3.3, I am not getting any errors on that code.

Output:

> string(0) "" string(3) "dev" string(4)
>   "prod" string(0) ""

Your error likely lies elsewhere. Please double check the reported line numbers.

Comment: PHP 5.3 works fine as I've stated in my answer, the problem only exists on prior versions of PHP. Check the Codepad link for an example.

Comment: My apologies, I thought you said it worked in prior versions, but in 5.3 it was failing.

Comment: No problem, I should have made my question more clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I came here by the reference: 
[Syntax error in PHP 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764170/syntax-error-in-php-5-2)
where Chandresh mentioned your link:
how ever one work around for PHP 5.2 is:

```
class Sample{
    public static $name;

    public function __construct(){
        self::$name = "User 1";
    }
}

$sample = new Sample();
$class = 'Sample';
$name = 'name';
$val_name = "";
$str = '$class::$$name';
eval("\$val_name = \"$str\";");
//echo $val_name."<br>";
eval("\$name = $val_name;");
echo $name;
```

Ignore if you already resolved. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

## Another case :

It may happen on some servers (PHP VERSION ??) if you use:
`if (empty(NAME_OF_A_CONSTANT)) ...`