# Static Method Not Working on Web Server in PHP

Tags: php, oop

I just finished working on a site in `PHP` and decided to upload it unto my web server, but when I try to run pages with static method calls I get this error `Unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM`. I know this has to do with double colon error, but I do not understand why it works on my local web server and refuses to work on my remote web server.

Due to this error, I had to through my whole site converting all static methods to instance methods

```
<?php
class User
{
    private $userId;

    public function __construct()
    {
        if(func_num_args() == 1)
        {
            $this->userId   =   func_get_arg(1);
        }
    }

    public static function userNameExists($name)
    {
        global $dbc;

        if(gettype($name) != "string")
        {
            die("Invalid Function Parameter");
        }

        $sql    =   "SELECT username FROM users WHERE users.username='$name'";
        $result =   mysqli_query($dbc, $sql) or die("Could Not Check Username at This Time: ".mysqli_error($dbc));

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {

            return false;
        }
    }
?>
```

When I call it:

```
<?php
   require("users.php");

   if(User::userNameExists($_GET['username']))
     header("Location:index.php");
?>
```

Comment: you need to post your code

Comment: Where is the code? In which line does this error occurs? What is the PHP version in both environments?

Comment: _I do not understand why it works on my local web server and refuses to work on my remote web server._ Probably because of different PHP versions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592322/php-expects-t-paamayim-nekudotayim

Comment: A `)` character is missing at the end of your `if(User::...` line

Comment: You're missing a quote in your second code snippet. Is this a typo or a direct copy from your source? Also, check your server's error log, as well its PHP version vs the version you're running locally. Finally, at least you know what the cryptic and stupid `T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM` is about!

Comment: Missing a `"` here too `require("users.php);`

Comment: The quote is my mistake when pasting the codes, I fixed that

Comment: global with oop hurts me ;/

Comment: @EpicWebDesign Please don't fix syntax errors in people's questions -- the problem they are having may in fact *be* the syntax error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the exact same code is working locally, but gives a syntax error on a live server, you might be using different PHP versions (an old PHP4 version on the server, perhaps).

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a `}` in the end of your code,

```
<?php
class User
{
    private $userId;

    public function __construct()
    {
        if(func_num_args() == 1)
        {
            $this->userId   =   func_get_arg(1);
        }
    }

    public static function userNameExists($name)
    {
        global $dbc;

        if(gettype($name) != "string")
        {
            die("Invalid Function Parameter");
        }
        //Think about escaping user input
        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($name);
        $sql    =   "SELECT username FROM users WHERE users.username='$name'";
        $result =   mysqli_query($dbc, $sql) or die("Could Not Check Username at This Time: ".mysqli_error($dbc));

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {

            return false;
        }
    }
}//This one
?>
```

You're also missing `"` in your require statement,

```
<?php
   require("users.php");//This one

   if(User::userNameExists($_GET['username']))
     header("Location:index.php");
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing parenthesis at the end of

> if(User::userNameExists($_GET['username'])

Do this instead

> if(User::userNameExists($_GET['username']))

Answer (score 1):

Try to check the `PHP` version of your web server and local machine.
You can refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995540/unexpected-t-paamayim-nekudotayim-in-php-5-2-x). You might have same problem and solution.