# PHP code change result - T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM

Tags: php, wordpress, parsing

in WordPress changed this code:

```
$highlight=$author_data->wp_capabilities['administrator']==1 ? "wall-admin" : "wall-registered";
```

to this:

```
if(isset(wp_capabilities['administrator']))
    {$highlight=$author_data->wp_capabilities['administrator']==1 ? "wall-admin" : "wall-registered";}
```

But result is this:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting :: (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM) in /wp-content/themes/oblivion/chat/wp-wall.php on line 196
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I know it's not the answer you hoped for, but please check google before asking around.

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592322/php-expects-t-paamayim-nekudotayim)

Comment: Also, please use proper code formatting. This will help us understand what you are doing (and maybe help yourself too)

Comment: i checked it but google doesn't tells where i have punctuation error in code, plus my knowledge in php is very poor

Comment: you forgot to learn Hebrew!!! https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=14492

Answer (score -3):

This line is wrong:

`if (isset(wp_capabilities['administrator']))`

`wp_capabilities` is **not** considered a variable, but like class name or function.

Obviously it should be:

`if (isset($author_data->wp_capabilities['administrator']))`

Comment: Nep, this code not solving my problem, still getting error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting :: (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM) in /homez.194/renopoin/www/sub_unagi2014/wp-content/themes/oblivion/chat/wp-wall.php on line 196