# What is the origin of the word "arisdottle"?

Tags: perl

An **arisdottle** is **::** and can be used when running `prove` to execute Perl tests.  The documentation for `prove` states that:

```
It is possible to supply arguments to tests. To do so separate them from
prove's own arguments with the arisdottle, '::'. For example

    prove -v t/mytest.t :: --url http://example.com

would run t/mytest.t with the options '--url http://example.com'. When
running multiple tests they will each receive the same arguments.
```

I'm interested in the origin of this term.  It's hard to Google. I asked in #toolchain on irc.perl.org and I have yet to get a concrete answer.  For historical reasons, I thought it would be helpful to document the term here.

Comment: [Andy Armstrong wrote that doc line](https://github.com/Perl-Toolchain-Gang/Test-Harness/commit/062737a4a2ce3d43af18baa2e1626d17040ea21d), he could likely confirm.

Comment: Not knowing any better, I changed the documentation entry for that in July 2013, and then reverted it a few days later after I was schooled. I don't have irc logs covering that time frame but I bet there is something relevant on #toolchain or #perl-qa. I do recall there was an article covering the history, on somewhere like perlmonks or use.perl.org.

Comment: Thanks for the links!  In comments on the first of those commits, Ovid [mentioned](https://github.com/Perl-Toolchain-Gang/Test-Harness/commit/d389ff4ce551a19f6fb8a2cdaaf7fc33bd5dcc27#commitcomment-3579159) that Aristotle suggested it and Andy picked the name as a tribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I worked on Test::Harness and prove.

While I don't remember specifically, it is likely a portmanteau of "dot" and "Aristotle". [Aristotle Pagaltzis](https://metacpan.org/author/ARISTOTLE) is a Perl contributor, [he contributed to Test::Harness](https://github.com/Perl-Toolchain-Gang/Test-Harness/blob/master/Changes#L804), and is probably the person who came up with the idea. [Aristotle is also credited with the Enterprise operator `( )x!!`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perlsecret/lib/perlsecret.pod#Enterprise).

[Andy Armstrong wrote that doc line](https://github.com/Perl-Toolchain-Gang/Test-Harness/commit/062737a4a2ce3d43af18baa2e1626d17040ea21d) and would likely be able to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced this is a piece of standard terminology at all. Every single usage of the word I can find online is either:

1. [A fragment of the documentation for `bin/prove`](https://metacpan.org/source/LEONT/Test-Harness-3.42/bin/prove#L125), like you found in your post
2. [A fragment of `Module::Metadata`](https://metacpan.org/source/ETHER/Module-Metadata-1.000033/lib/Module/Metadata.pm#L60)
3. A reference to a domain name "arisdottle.net" formerly owned by [AMIRI](https://metacpan.org/author/AMIRI), which has since expired.
4. Unrelated content, including some misspellings of the name Aristotle.

There doesn't appear to be any wider usage -- and, anecdotally, I've never heard it. There's certainly no language-independent term for the usage of `::` as a package separator; [PHP, famously, had to invent their own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592322/php-expects-t-paamayim-nekudotayim).

Comment: While there may not be any wider usage, I worked on that project. It's a very specific thing to Perl.

Comment: It does come up a few times: https://grep.cpan.me/?q=arisdottle  A lot of these instances seem to be copy/paste, but it's a word that gets used, even if a wider audience is not aware of it.

Comment: @oalders Almost all of those look like copies of Module::Metadata, often via cpanm. There's one or two additional usages I missed, but nothing that looks especially significant.

Comment: @duskwuff The question is about the origin of the term, not whether the term is significant.

Comment: @duskwuff that's why I said "A lot of these instances seem to be copy/paste"

Answer (score 1):

Oh yeah - better late than never - that's was me and, yes, it was a reference to https://metacpan.org/author/ARISTOTLE